# Is there any way in Hugo by which i can put page title in range statement

Tags: templates, markdown, hugo, static-site

I was trying to make a template page in Hugo. I wanted to list all the pages which have the tag same as the title of the current page. Is there any way by which I can put value of ".Title" in place of "hard-coded-tag" as shown in the code below.

```
<h3>Perfumes by {{ .Title }}</h3>
<div>
    <ul>
    {{ range .Site.Taxonomies.tags.hard-coded-tag }}
        <li><a href="{{ .Page.URL }}">{{ .Page.Params.perfume.name }}</a></li>
    {{ end }}
    </ul>
</div>
```

> storing the value of “.Title” in some variable {{ $someVariable := .Title }} and the replacing hard-coded-category with it. I didn’t work.

> Tried same using $scratch.Set, that also didn’t work

Answer (score 3):

I do this type of thing on [my portal pages](https://www.ii.com/portals/). The trick¹ is to use [the index function](https://gohugo.io/functions/index-function/), for example something like this:

```
<h3>Perfumes by {{ .Title }}</h3>
<div>
    <ul>
    {{ range (index .Site.Taxonomies.tags .Title) }}
        <li><a href="{{ .Page.URL }}">{{ .Page.Params.perfume.name }}</a></li>
    {{ end }}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, set a variable first and use it, e.g.:

```
{{ $t := .Title }}

<h3>Perfumes by {{ $t }}</h3>
<div>
    <ul>
    {{ range (index .Site.Taxonomies.tags $t) }}
        <li><a href="{{ .Page.URL }}">{{ .Page.Params.perfume.name }}</a></li>
    {{ end }}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

¹ I learned about this in discourse.gohugo.io's thread [Regular page parameter inside a range](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/regular-page-parameter-inside-a-range/21572).

Comment: Thanks, man. it worked with little modification. In place of $t I used ($t | urlize) and it worked like charm